# Распространяется ли LSP на абстрактные методы?

Tags: c#, ооп, solid

Ведь у них нет реализации [image: На фото 2 примера, в первом случае добавляется дополнительно предусловие, он не проходит LSP, а второй случай ?]

На фото 2 примера, в первом случае добавляется дополнительно предусловие, он нарушает LSP, а второй случай ?

Comment: Никогда и нигде не выкладывайте текстовую информацию в виде картинки. С картники код крайне неудобно копировать.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Применение принципа подстановки не зависит от абстрактности классов/методов. Если первый пример нарушает принцип, то и второй скорее всего тоже. Для того чтобы дать точный ответ нужно каким-то образом описать поведение `GetNumber`.

В оригинальной публикации принцип подстановки требует наличие у базового класса некой спецификации, которой должны удовлетворять все наследники:

> What is needed is a stronger requirement that constrains the behavior of subtypes: properties that can be proved using the specification of an object’s presumed
> type should hold even though the object is actually a member of a subtype of that
> type:
>
> *Subtype Requirement: Let φ(z) be a property provable about objects x
> of type T. Then φ(y) should be true for objects y of type S where S is
> a subtype of T.*
>
> **A type’s specification determines what properties we can prove about objects.**
>
> [A Behavioral Notion of Subtyping](http://www.csnell.net/computerscience/Liskov_subtypes.pdf) Barbara H. Liskov, Jeannette M. Wing, 1994

Нельзя просто посмотреть на код базового класса и понять что должны делать наследники. «Делай также как у предка» — размытое требование, которое приводит к недопониманию. Принцип задуман как средство разрешения логических противоречий в иерархии классов, а не для построчного сравнения кода.

Соответственно, неважно является ли базовый класс абстрактным или нет. Важно какой логике он должен следовать и что от него ожидает вызывающий код.

В данном примере у метода `GetNumber` нет ни спецификации на формальном языке ни тестов, даже документации нет. Все что есть это один пример использования классов в коде. И этот пример ломается, если `GetNumber` выбрасывает исключение, т.е. класс `B` нарушает LSP.

С другой стороны, можно в документации класса `A` (пример № 1) или `Base` (№ 2) указать, что `GetNumber` выбрасывает исключение если передан некорректный аргумент (см. документацию [`Stream.BeginRead`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.beginread?view=netcore-3.1) там в подобных случаях выбрасывается `ArgumentException`). И тогда получится что нарушения принципа в обоих случаях нет, просто клиентский код написан с ошибками.

Answer (score 2):

Не смотря на то, что у абстрактного класса нет поведения по умолчанию, у него может быть предполагаемое поведение, описанное в документации.

Подобное поведение может быть описано и для методов интерфейсов.

В том коде, который вы привели, метод `GetNumber` из-за префикса *Get* воспринимается как геттер, который не должен ничего ломать. Читая код, я бы предположил, что он не может бросить исключение. Я бы, скорее, ожидал исключения от сеттера, который устанавливает значение поля `num`.

Но это всё общие рассуждения и опыт использования похожего кода. Формально никаких оснований для LSP здесь нет, потому что действительно нет эталонной базовой реализации метода и нет документации, которая бы предписывала методы определённое поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Liskov Substitution Principle?
Если в интерфейс добавлен метод, то он для чего-то нужен. По-научному описание того, что должен делать метод, называется контракт метода.
LSP постулирует, что в наследниках не должны нарушаться контракты.